# By myself I have many meanings

Tags: riddle

Left alone, I am very agreeable

> Three of us is bad news
>
> With two of my next door neighbors I become a hero
>
> I also can take off with same two neighbors
>
> Some other neighbors really like me. I can make them bigger and
>   powerful

Who am I? And who are these neighbors?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Left alone, I am very agreeable

> **k** - agreeable as a clipping of OK as 'kay.

Three of us is bad news

> KKK - the racist group.

With two of my next door neighbors I become a hero

> MLK - Martin Luther King, who advanced civil rights.

I also can take off with same two neighbors

> KLM - Koninklijke Luchtvaart Maatschappij (Royal Aviation Company), the Dutch airline.

Some other neighbors really like me. I can make them bigger and powerful

> k turns unit letters a thousand times larger as the prefix kilo, such as J(oule) to kJ.

Comment: Yes I was thinking Kg and Kw

Comment: The same two next door neighbors also work, as does the one Tom mentioned :)

Answer (score 6):

Am I

> Oxygen?

By myself I have many meanings

> Oxygen can mean either the atom, ion, or molecule

Left alone, I am very agreeable

> Oxygen ions and molecules are rarely bad

Three of us is bad news

> O3, Ozone, is quite toxic and a harmful byproduct of chemical plants

With two of my next door neighbors I become a hero

> H20 and either Nx0 or SxO, water and useful chemicals

I also can take off with same two neighbors

> any of these come in gaseous forms in normal earthen temperatures

Some other neighbors really like me. I can make them bigger and powerful

> Many other elements can oxidize, metals can make strong alloys in the right ratios

Answer (score 4):

Left alone, I am very agreeable

> 6 is a Perfect Number

Three of us is bad news

> 666 is the Number of the Beast

With two of my next door neighbors I become a hero

> Hero 767 is “a very well-established Chinese brand of fountain pens” according to [inksandpens.com](https://www.inksandpens.com/post/first-impressions-hero-767/).

I also can take off with same two neighbors

> The Boeing 767 is a plane

Some other neighbors really like me. I can make them bigger and powerful

> I guessed this is a reference to the 777 and 787 planes, but on reflection, perhaps this is about Friendly Numbers? 6 is the smallest of those, after all, and 42 (6 × 7), 56, 66, and 96 are also "friendly”. In addition, 36 (6²) is a Powerful Number.

Who am I? And who are these neighbors?

> The digit 6, and its near neighbours (especially 7).